# Add class to Bootstrap login form button

Tags: theming

I want to add a class to a button in my login form. I have searched through all the template files and I cannot find where to do this. I found the following code that best matches the form in modules/user/user.module

```
function user_login_block($form) {
$form['#action'] = url(current_path(), array('query' => drupal_get_destination(), 'external' => FALSE));
$form['#id'] = 'user-login-form';
$form['#validate'] = user_login_default_validators();
$form['#submit'][] = 'user_login_submit';
```

The HTML for the button is below. My aim is to change btn-default to btn-primary

```
<button class="btn btn-default form-submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Log in" type="submit">Log in</button>
```

Please help!

Comment: I managed to get to work by adding $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'btn-primary'; to   function user_login_block($form) {... in modules/user/user.module. As I understand it changes like this should be done in the subtheme folder but when I add it there it displays an error about unable to redeclare a function

Comment: If you encounter the above error, make sure your Sub theme name is declared correctly in your subthemes .info file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refrain from hacking core.

Rather add this code to your sub theme's template.php file:

```
function MYTHEME_button(&$variables) {
  dpm($variables);
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $label = $element['#value'];
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'value', 'type'));

  // If a button type class isn't present then add in default.
  $button_classes = array(
    'btn-default',
    'btn-primary',
    'btn-success',
    'btn-info',
    'btn-warning',
    'btn-danger',
    'btn-link',
  );
  $class_intersection = array_intersect($button_classes, $element['#attributes']['class']);
  if ($variables['element']['#type'] == 'submit' && $variables['element']['#value'] == 'Log in') {
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'btn-primary';
  }
  else if (empty($class_intersection)) {
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'btn-default';
  }

  // Add in the button type class.
  $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-' . $element['#button_type'];

  // This line break adds inherent margin between multiple buttons.
  // dpm($variables);
  return '<button' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $label . "</button>\n";
}
```

Bootstrap theme overrides the theme_button, and this is where I copied this code (minus the alteration of adding the class). We then override Bootstrap's implementation with our own.

The code that adds the class is this part:

```
if ($variables['element']['#type'] == 'submit' && $variables['element']['#value'] == 'Log in') {
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'btn-primary';
}
```

It's perhaps no the best way to detect that specific button (going on type and text), but it works.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was after. I really didn't want to hack the core. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [`hook_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). You can add and change (I would suggest only adding unless you are sure it will only affect the forms you want it to) classes with [`#attributes`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attributes)