# Add class to button with specific class

Tags: theming, hooks

I'm trying to add the class 'on-load-click' to any btn with the class 'webform-submit'

```
<div class="form-actions"><button class="webform-submit button-primary btn btn-primary form-submit" type="submit" name="op" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

Currently I have this:

```
function ntc_bootstrap_hook_form_webform_client_form_alter(&$variables) {
  dpm($variables);
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $label = $element['#value'];
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'value', 'type'));

  $class_intersection = array_intersect($button_classes, $element['#attributes']['class']);

  if ($variables['element']['#type'] == 'submit' && $variables['element']['#value'] == 'Submit' && $variables['element']['class'] == 'webform-submit') {
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'load-on-click';
  }

}
```

However it isn't working and I don't know why. I was following this [Add class to Bootstrap login form button](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/142428/add-class-to-bootstrap-login-form-button) to help me, but I can't work it out. Currently there is an error on the button saying "Uncaught Syntax error: unexpected token ';' ", however I'm unsure if it is related. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you want to add the class to $element directly you need to assign the variable by reference: `$element = &$variables['element'];`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, is that not already on there?

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#language.operators.assignment.reference